# allow directory browsing in the apache2.conf file - not working

Tags: server, apache2

I am trying to allow directory browsing in the `apache2.conf` file, but when restarting the server, I get an error. This error make the web server crash and I can't get access to the localhost directory. So I have to remove this line of code again, to make server available. How can I allow directory browsing to a specific folder in my web server? Is it possible to allow directory access from the `apache2.conf` file?

Here is a clip from my code in Ubuntu:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is a typo in your code. `AllowOvveride`  should be `AllowOverride`.

Here are few other tips:

```bsh
Alias /nytest /var/www/nytest                              # this directive will make the directory accessible at http://localgost/nytest in case that your DocumentRoot is not '/var/www/' but '/var/www/html/' as it is by default
<Directory /var/www/nytest>
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* # better appearance
    DirectoryIndex Disabled                                # disable the 'execution' of the index files
    AllowOverride None                                     # disable .htaccess files
    AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .phtml .php5 # display these file types as plain text
    php_admin_flag engine off                              # don't run arbitrary PHP code; if you've other scripting languages, disable them too.
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
I tried it, but i get an error saying "You don't have permission to access / on this server. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe". What could be the reason for this error, do i need to change the .htaccess file?